# The nan error for all possible case i enter

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

The output is to print out the farthest number from x from array
my code, for all case, only print out nan, I have been staring at my code for hours but still got nothing, even though I know something went wrong.

It doesn't show any error. So, I don't really know what to do, I'm a newbie, and I know this question may sound kinda dumb, but can somebody help me please :((

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 100
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
void nhap(float a[] ,int &n)
{
    int x;
    do
       {
        cout<< "\nnhap so n: ";
        cin >> n;
        cout<< "\nnhap so x: ";
        cin >> x;
    if(n<0 || n> MAX)
        cout << "\nsai roi, moi nhap lai ";
        }
        while(n<0 || n >MAX);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
            cout << "a[" << i << "]= ";
            cin >> a[i];
            }
}
void xuat(float a[], int &n)
{
    for(int i=0; i <n; i++)
    {
    cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
}
void taomang (float a[], float b[], int &n, int x)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        b[i] = abs(a[i] - x);
}
float xaxnhat(float a[], float b[], int &n)
{
    int s = b[0];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(b[i]>s)
        {
            s=b[i];
        }
    }
        return s;
}
float xuatketqua (float a[], float b[], int n)
{
    int k = xaxnhat(a,b,n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (b[i] == k)
            return a[i];
    }
}
int main()
{
int n;
float a[MAX];
float b[MAX];
nhap(a,n);
xuat(a,n);
cout << " \ngia tri xa gia tri x nhat la: ";
cout << xuatketqua(a,b,n);
return 0;
}
```

for example array: 19 434 23 55 7
x: 2
then the farthest value from x is: 434

Comment: *for example array: 19 434 23 55 7 x: 2 then the farthest value from x is: 434* Could you please hardcore it in your [mcve] and remove std::cin completely and std::cout mostly so nobody who wants to help you would not have to input these numbers in a terminal.

Comment: Take advantage of the most-secret tool, the debugger, to step through your program to see what it is doing and inspect the variables to see why.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are reading `b` defined in `main` uninitialized in `xaxnhat` called though `xuatketqua` from `cout << xuatketqua(a,b,n);`. This causes undefined behavior.
2. `xuatketqua` does not have a return value in all branches. If `k` is not found in the loop, then there will be no return statement at the end of the function's control flow, again causing undefined behavior.
3. `xaxnhat` does not use the first parameter `float a[]`, seems suspect.
4. `taomang` is not used. Did you intend to initialize `b` from `main` through this function before handing of to `xuatketqua`?